# How to automatically start, execute and stop EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, gpu

I want to test my Python library in GPU machine once a day.
I decided to use AWS EC2 for testing.
However, the fee of gpu machine is very high, so I want to stop the instance after the test ends.

Thus, I want to do the followings once a day automatically

1. Start EC2 instance (which is setup manually)
2. Execute command (test -> push logs to S3)
3. Stop EC2 (not remove)

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple...

**Run script on startup**

To run a script automatically when the instance starts (*every* time it starts, not just the first time), put your script in this directory:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

**Stop instance when test has finished**

Simply issue a shutdown command to the operating system at the end of your script:

```
sudo shutdown now -h
```

Comment: Is it possible to start instance without execute the script under ../per-boot?
I want to login the instance after putting the script, but it shutdown the instance.

Comment: I presume that you have already installed the script? That's an interesting situation... if the script doesn't run for long (or has an error), it will shutdown very quickly. I think you would need to detach the disk, attach it to another EC2 instance, then remove the script from that directory, and then put the disk back. It's probably worth modifying the script to _not_ shutdown if a particular tag is present, to allow for such situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can push script logs to  custom coudwatch namespaces. Like when the process ends publish a state to cloudwatch. In cloudwatch create alarms based on the state of process, so if it has a completed state trigger an AWS lambda function that will stop instance after completion of your job.

Also if you want to start and stop on specific time you can use ec2 instance scheduler to start/stop instances. It just works like a cron job at specific intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aws cli

To start an instance you would do the following

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

and to stop the instance you would do the following

```
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

To execute commands inside the machine, you will need to ssh into it and run the commands that you need, then you can use the aws cli to upload files to s3

```
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt
```

I suggest reading the aws cli documentation, you will find most if not all what you need to automate aws commands [there](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/).

Answer (score 0):

I created a shell script to start an EC2 instance -if not already running,- connect via SSH and, if you want, run a command.

https://gist.github.com/jotaelesalinas/396812f821785f76e5e36cf928777a12

You can use it in three different ways:

`./ec2-start-and-ssh.sh -i <instance id> -s`

will show status information about your instance: running state and private and public IP addresses.

`./ec2-start-and-ssh.sh -i <instance id>`

will connect and leave you inside the default shell.

`./ec2-start-and-ssh.sh -i <instance id> <command>`

will run whatever command you specify, e.g.:

`./ec2-start-and-ssh.sh -i <instance id> ./run.sh`

`./ec2-start-and-ssh.sh -i <instance id> sudo poweroff`

I use the last two commands to run periodic jobs minimizing billing costs.

I hope this helps!