# How can I connect to my EC2 Instance via SSH with an AWS Lambda Function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to ssh into an ec2 instance with a lambda function. I keep receiving a null value for my response every time I try run my function with my logs displaying the following error:

```
START RequestId: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx Version: $LATEST
2020-02-19T22:56:16.574Z    xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx    INFO    failed connection, boo
2020-02-19T22:56:16.576Z    xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx    INFO    Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:687:19)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
  level: 'client-timeout'
}
```

With it being a timed out error, I figured it was an issue with connecting to the instance rather than my code, but the lambda is apart of the same VPC that the EC2 is apart of, along with a security group enabling ssh connections. I'm also able to connect to ssh into the instance manually as well.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

  const fs = require('fs')
  const SSH = require('simple-ssh');
  const pemfile = 'xxx.pem';
  const user = 'ec2-user';
  const host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';


  // all this config could be passed in via the event
  const ssh = new SSH({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    key: fs.readFileSync(pemfile)
  });

  let cmd = "ls";
  if (event.cmd == "long") {
    cmd += " -l";
  }

  let prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    let ourout = "";

    ssh.exec('mkdir /home/ec2-user/ssh_success', {
      exit: function() {
        ourout += "\nsuccessfully exited!";
        resolve(ourout);
      },
      out: function(stdout) {
        ourout += stdout;
      }
    }).start({
      success: function() {
        console.log("successful connection!");
      },
      fail: function(e) {
        console.log("failed connection, boo");
        console.log(e);
      }
    });

  });

  const res = await prom;

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: res,
  };
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Your Lambda is deployed into the VPC, yes? If you haven't already, increase your Lambda timeout from the default of 3 seconds. ENI attachment may take longer.

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you'd like to connect from Lambda to EC2 via SSH? There might be a better way to accomplish your end-goal, such as using Systems Manager Session Manager or message queues.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein What I wanted to do was click a submit file in a front end application that would call a lambda to pick up a file from an s3 bucket and store it in an ec2  using an aws cli command via the ssh library. If there is a better way of accomplishing that I'd love to hear your suggestion. I know I could do it manually sshing into the ec2 and calling the command, but I wanted to automate the process

Comment: Can you tell us more about "pick up a file from an s3 bucket and store it there"? Do you mean store it on the EC2 instance? If so, what will the file be doing there? Is there some script that should then be triggered to process the file?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein   That's correct. The file from the s3 bucket would be downloaded onto the instance for another script on the ec2 to process the file

Comment: Given your requirements, I would **recommend against using SSH**. For a similar situation, see: [Can't sync s3 with ec2 folder from aws lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60205563/174777)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I will try this out. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @JohnStone were you able to solve this via the above comment suggestion, or a different solution? I am facing the same problem myself right now and am curious what worked best for you.

Comment: @The_DemoCorgin Yes, this is the solution that I ended up using aws Systems Manager:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60470604/why-can-my-code-run-in-a-standard-node-js-file-but-not-in-a-aws-lambda-function

Comment: @JohnStone Sorry forgot to reply earlier. Thanks! Got this working for myself as well.