# Copy a File From S3 to EC2 Automatically

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

**It's being a while I'm struggling with this situation:**

1. I have a local application in PHP (WordPress)
2. When I commit my changes I send the changed files automatically to
   S3 via Git Hooks
3. S3 Bucket receives these changed files
4. Right after this, I send a notification to a lambda function when
   the file is included/deleted
5. In the lambda function, using javascript for instance, I have
   identified the bucket and file names (So far so good).

**The question is: How can I copy this file from the Bucket to the EC2 to complete my automation ?**

*What I have tried so far:*

A) Manually speaking I can do something like this inside my ec2 instance, that works perfectly:

aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket "\var\www\html*" --exclude "wp-config.php"

B) Also I have executed one similar command on "SSM Run Command" like this that also works perfectly:

wget https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.txt

C) Trying to create a very simple SSM document that execute a simple random bash script like I have done in the previous attempt, trying to create the document - create command or session - session type and trying some versions of what you can see in this example (with/whitout quotations...):

```
---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Command Document Example JSON Template"
parameters:
  Message:
    type: "String"
    description: "Example"
    default: "Hello World"
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runPowerShellScript"
  name: "example"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
      - cd /var/www/html
      - wget https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.txt
```

**With this error: failed to run commands: fork/exec /usr/bin/pwsh: no such file or directory (even trying with and without quotes)**

If someone have some idea, maybe a code somewhere to help me automate the copy of a single file from S3 to EC2 this would be very apreciated !!!

Thank You guys in advance ! :)

Comment: Run Command seems as a good fit.  Do you use linux? Why not use run command for linux? Do you need powershell?

Comment: The error you get indicates that you don't have powershell installed. Should try `AWS-RunShellScript` document.

Comment: Marcin, thank you so much, you pointed me to the right direction ! I'll be trying tomorrow execute this on Lambda (with the proper permissions etc...) Tks :)

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hello again !! I concluded that using a personalized document I would not be able to determine an instanceid. After research a lot on the web I found out that I could just execute the aws sdk sendCommand inside the lambda with the pre existent document "aws:runShellScript" or "aws:runPowerShellScript" but for a change... I'm struggling to provade a versy simple example in nodejs. Would you by any chance have a very simple working example using sendCommand ? Thank You in Advance !

Comment: I'm not using node.js unfortunately. But I could provide some guidance for boto3 if this would help?

Comment: At the very end, after lots of tries I was able to solve this issue with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60470604/why-can-my-code-run-in-a-standard-node-js-file-but-not-in-a-aws-lambda-function the comand in this post the way it is was the solution ! But thank you very much for all your help !!!

Comment: Thanks Marcin, you are always spot on!

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost got it, you can try execute the SSM document using lambda and document should execute the AWS CLI inside the instance.

Things to consider:

1. The instance should have the correct permissions (IAM Role) to download the file from S3
2. The instance should have AWS CLI installed on it
3. The instance should be part of SSM Inventory (you will need also an IAM Role)

Also I'm not sure why are you trying to copy a file in a block storage that is already in S3, I think is not cost efficient.

Comment: Hello Mauricio, thank you for your comments, I've discovered with "Marcin" comment what was wrong on my ssm document and I was able to fix it. About your comment of efficiency I understand what you say, I'm just trying to automatize my local development (in PHP) to deploy changed files of my web site on an ec2 instance that's why (maybe if you have a different way to do this I accept suggestions !) Tks